# Flatten Nested Defaultdict List in Python before Conversion to Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a rather large `defaultdict (list)` with a large number of keys and values. The size of the list is also variable.

I was wondering what's the Pythonic way to unpack such nested structure before writing it to `Pandas DataFrame`. I want one value in a (row,col) in the `DataFrame`.

**Code**

```
from collections import defaultdict
import pandas as pd


dict_one_needle = defaultdict(list)
new_default_dict = defaultdict(list)
needle_data = []

# some mock-up data
dict_one_needle['PatientID'].append('999')
dict_one_needle['PatientName'].append('another')
dict_one_needle['LesionNr'].append('two')
dict_one_needle['NeedleNr'].append(None)
# more mock-up data
for idx_s in range(0, 3):
    dict_one_needle['PatientID'].append('123')
    dict_one_needle['PatientName'].append('john doe')
    dict_one_needle['LesionNr'].append(1)
    dict_one_needle['NeedleNr'].append(2)

# append to list
needle_data.append(dict_one_needle)

# some mock-up data
new_default_dict['PatientID'].append(0)
new_default_dict['PatientName'].append('rs')
new_default_dict['LesionNr'].append(0)
new_default_dict['NeedleNr'].append(0)

# append again to list
needle_data.append(new_default_dict)

# unpack the nested list of defaultdict(list)
new_dict = defaultdict(list)
for needles in needle_data:
    # take each key of the dictionary, each value
    for keys, vals in needles.items():
        for val in vals:
            new_dict[keys].append(val)

#convert to DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(new_dict)
```